# Is there a way to create a general access point entry in Netplan?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-manager, network-bridge, netplan

Is it necessary for me to create an access-point entry for each AP I use in order to use VirtualBox's bridge adapter?

**Edit:** this was the netplan config I tried before network completely crashed.  Right now, it's back to the default config.

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

# Added everything from here myself
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
#  wifis:
#    wlp2s0:
#      access-points: {...}
#      dhcp4: true
#      dhcp6: true

  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp1s0, wlp2s0]
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
```

Network completely crashed (segmentation fault) when I first did this because of newline.  Never recovered even after removing them, even with using the original/default config file.  Had to restart my laptop.

*Edit 2:* After running `netplan --debug generate`, this returned:

```
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:7696): DEBUG: 12:42:59.421: Processing input file //etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml..
** (generate:7696): DEBUG: 12:42:59.421: starting new processing pass
** (generate:7696): DEBUG: 12:42:59.421: wlp2s0: setting default backend to 2
** (generate:7696): DEBUG: 12:42:59.421: br0: setting default backend to 2
** (generate:7696): DEBUG: 12:42:59.421: enp1s0: setting default backend to 2
** (generate:7696): DEBUG: 12:42:59.421: Generating output files..
** (generate:7696): DEBUG: 12:42:59.421: networkd: definition wlp2s0 is not for us (backend 2)
** (generate:7696): DEBUG: 12:42:59.421: networkd: definition br0 is not for us (backend 2)
** (generate:7696): DEBUG: 12:42:59.421: networkd: definition enp1s0 is not for us (backend 2)
```

Comment: As long as your ethernet adapter is operable, then VB's bridge adapter should be able to use it directly.

Comment: what if I'm on WiFi? @heynnema

Comment: It should work the same. The VB bridge should bridge whatever your primary connection method is.

Comment: So in addition to the wired interface in the ethernet section, I'll also add an entry for wireless interface as well?

Comment: If you're actually using Netplan, instead of NetworkManager, then yes. Edit your question to include the output of `sudo more /etc/netplan/*.yaml`, and report back to @heynnema

Comment: Just did. @heynnema

BTW, network totally crashed when I first did it because of new lines, but never recovered afterwards

Comment: For NetworkManager, your `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` file should contain just the first 4 lines. Then do `sudo netplan generate` and `sudo netplan apply`. Then configure your wireless just the way that you used to do it in earlier versions of Ubuntu. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema the first 4 lines, meaning until `renderer: NetworkManager`?  If that's what you meant, then I did do that.  While I was unable to do bridge networking via wireless, it was fine in wired mode.

Comment: Yes, the renderer should be the last line.